# Check which bound DataGridViewColumn is clicked on

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs` object provided in the events (eg CellMouseDown, CellDoubleClicked) gives the column as a numeric index in `DataGridView.Columns` but I don't want to hardcode a number into my event handler.  I'm using a strongly typed dataset and am wondering if there's a way to find out what the column index for `MyDataRowType.TheColumnImLookingFor` in the DGV is programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following to get the matching column:

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == _myDataSet.DataTable1.DataColumn2Column.ColumnName)
{
    // Do Work 
}
```